# Exporting to CSV file while spider is running using Scrapy

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, pipeline

I'm trying to export scraped data to a CSV using Scrapy such that I'm able to utilize the data in the CSV file *while* my spider is running. Currently, I'm only able to generate a CSV file filled with data when my spider is finished scraping. My current pipeline is very simple:

```
class ReDataSpiderPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('stored_RE_data.csv', 'wb')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
```

I've been through the Scrapy documentation and haven't been able to figure this out, but I imagine it's how many people using Scrapy would want their pipelines to work so I'm assuming I'm missing something simple. My goal is just to be able to start analyzing the CSV data as it comes in while the spider is still running rather than having to wait until the spider is finished before I can look at the data.

Thanks in advance.